# Wordpress not reading custom css?

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

I'm using Woocommerce with a theme called "mystyles", up til now every change i've made in its custom.css file has worked, but for some reason today no matter what change I make it isn't working! I've even edited the css of the site within the browser using devtools for chrome and it's worked perfectly but once I upload it to the actual website it reverts to the old css from a few days ago. I don't understand! I've tried uploading from both FTP and the in-wordpress editor, double checked to make sure the changes were uploaded by re-downloading the file and found nothing wrong. Checked in different browsers, cleared caches, it's driving me INSANE. Any ideas? The website is www.bettinasboutique.com it's in the process of being set up (if i can figure this poop out).

Have any of you had a problem with wordpress not accepting changes to css?

I've also tried making changes to the html files, specifically to the text in the nav bars which is the spot that is causing me the most trouble, and it's worked fine! it's only the CSS.

I've even tried uploading my custom css to the original stylesheet file instead of the custom css file and it STILL reads the old nav styles. Please help!

Comment: all the <head> tags are in the body, is that normal? could you please illustrate where your custom style sheet should be?

Comment: double and triple check you are editing the proper file.

Comment: It is always browser cache problem in my cases. So I simple Ctrl + Shift + R for Chrome and Ctrl + F5 for IE ...

Comment: also -- you have  some markup at the top of the document which should no be there: 
<div id="yelloww"></div>
<div id="yellow">
<a href="http://bettinasboutique.com/"><img src="img/logo.gif" border="0"></a>
</div>

Comment: i def am, it should be here: www.bettinasboutique.com/wp-content/themes/mystile/custom.css and it is

Comment: Is the nav popping up with a red background for you guys or white background grayish text?

Comment: It is a red background for me

Comment: What happens when you open custom.css and delete everything? (make a copy first) Does it blow away the styles?

Comment: And sometimes I forget to change the css link source that I set as absolute path and it still tries to look at my local server, so it doesn't work. I am just saying my experiences since it works in your developing environment but fails on production. (And unfortunately I cannot access your website, just sharing my mistakes I mostly do considering it might help).

Comment: if you delete custom.css it reverts to style.css, the way the original writer of the layout i'm editing wrote it, there is a main "style.css" and any custom css you copy & paste and change into "custom.css" and it should overwrite style.css

Comment: I tried also putting the code into style.css and that didn't take either